# Why can an employee of a company shut down a question about its software?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, privileges

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708196/memory-error-when-trying-to-train-ml-model), asking how to resolve a bug from an extension created by NVIDIA. I included the specific command that I used, the output it gave me, a traceback of the error it gave me, and a link to the github repository it was based on. This is at least as much information as I see in a typical SO  question.

But then it was closed by "desertnaut", "MBT", and Robert Crovella, a NVIDIA employee, with "edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error...". I put significant effort into writing the question so that the problematic behavior and how to replicate it would be clear. Looking at other questions on SO, my question is up to par. A library extension from NVIDIA has problematic behavior that me and others are interested in resolving.

Then a NVIDIA employee has the power to close the question for not providing a "specific problem or error"? I haven't used SO much, but is this really okay?

Comment: Can't speak to the quality of the specific question, but there seems to be only 1 employee of NVIDIA involved in closing the question/  So he only provided 1/3 of the close votes. This seems to be less of an "employee" shutting my question down, rather than "why was my questions closed"

Answer (score 24):

The privileges to close a question have nothing to do with the person being an NVIDIA employee. Rather, they are granted based upon [reputation earned on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Reputation is gained by posting content that has been marked as useful and relevant by other users.

Three different users were involving in making the decision that your question as written did not contain [enough information to be answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and they all reached the same decision independently.

That an NVIDIA employee monitors questions with the [nvidia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) tag is not particularly surprising. It is actually a good thing. These folks are likely to be the most knowledgeable about, and thus in the best position to answer and/or moderate, the questions.

This is outside of my subject-matter expertise, so I really can't comment on whether or not there is sufficient information provided in your question to allow it to be answered. But I *suspect* that there isn't. Consider providing code that reproduces the problem. This is what the close reason is trying to tell you:

> **Edit the question to include** desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**. This will help others answer the question.

Comment: I agree NVIDIA employees are experts on this topic, but they also have a conflict of interest in shoving bugs in their products under the rug. 2 other people voted yes, but the important thing to me is: the NVIDIA employee's vote is the straw that decides whether my question pointing to a problem in NVIDIA software can stay open. That doesn't seem like a very fair arrangement.

Comment: I included the specific, concise command anyone can run to replicate the problem. I detailed the inputs, outputs, and errors. I referenced the source code and the platform. I gave full detail for my problem and how to reproduce it, while the NVIDIA employee and the two others didn't. It feels uncomfortable that with the information literally all there, as clearly and thoroughly as I could put it, you're suspecting they're in the right in their 0-detail accusation.

Comment: My question has been reopened by three other users, but it now has a terrible -4 votes. I scrolled through 20 pages questions with similar tags, I didn't see one with such a poor rating as mine. Is my question really that bad? Look at the hundreds of others in much better standing, around the same time and about the same topic. Does SO have no way to reverse or penalize dogpiling?

Comment: The folks who made the extension are looking into this bug. It doesn't really matter now if anyone answers the question here on SO. But when I first asked it, a bunch of other people really wanted to figure it out. That some powerful users can shut it down and, after I post in meta, make it the worst rated question among hundreds in its category, with no way to get it back into positive standing... it just gives me a bad feeling about SO. If someone had that experience with a community I ran I'd want to know and correct it. I know you're not an admin, I just wanted to put it here into writing.

Comment: @histrionics You've posted more than I can hope to respond to in a comment. That the NVIDIA employee happened to be the last vote is really just coincidence, and not as significant as you're making it. This is emphatically *not* NVIDIA employees sweeping bugs under the rug. If they wanted to do that, they'd do it on their tech support line, not here. Clearly, they are not interested in doing that. As far as the voting, that's called the Meta effect: discussing questions on Meta tends to attract a higher-than-usual amount of attention and therefore votes. Your accusations here, regarding...

Comment: ...the way that the close-voting system works, and what appeared to be an attack against the ethics of one of the individual close-voters, was perceived somewhat negatively by the Meta crowd, thus (unfortunately) resulted in some downvotes against your question. Some downvotes aren't really a big deal, in the scheme of things. Whether those downvotes are actually merited, or even whether the original closure was justified, I cannot comment on, because I just don't know enough about the subject matter to say whether you had all the required information.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your discussion Cody, I appreciate it. Should I delete this question to prevent it from spiraling further?

Comment: @histrionics You don't see any other posts in the tag with a less than 3 score because they got deleted. Employees and subject experts _want to help_ people in the tags they are experts in. They _want to know_ about bugs and issues in their software. The employee you mention has answered hundreds of questions in the tag. The tag is an extension of their support forum or github issues thread. The idea that the closure is part of a silencing campaign is the least likely explanation.